# Dynamic JSX element/tag names

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, jsx

I'm just wanted to know if there is a best practice approach to rendering an element with ReactJS dynamically

Consider these scenarios:

**(1) Parameter Factory component:**
A parameterised factory component whose job is to render a component ***based on a string parameter***, is there a way of doing so without having to revert to React.createElement?

```js
<pre><code>// The following doesn't work
class Quiz extends React.Component{
  constructor (props){
    super (props);
    this.state = {
      questionText: '',
      correctAnswer: [],
      assetType: ['DragNDrop','MultipleChoice','MatchPairs']
    }
  }
  render(){
    const { questionText, correctAnswer } = this.state;
    return <{this.state.assetType[this.props.typeIndex] />;
  }
}
</code></pre>
```

**(2)Dynamic HTML tags:**
Render a different HTML header tag based on an integer input. For this, I initially tried to use Template strings but had to resort to conditional rendering.

```js
<pre><code>// No joy with Template strings
render (){
  <{`h${this.state.headerSize}`}>
    {this.state.headerText}
  </ {`h${this.state.headerSize}`}>
}
```

I like using JSX, and it would be nice to be able to use dynamic element names with it for consistency.

I'm also aware that:

```js
assetType: ['DragNDrop','MultipleChoice','MatchPairs']
```

can be stored as:

```js
assetType: [<DragNDrop />,<MultipleChoice />, <MatchPairs />]
```

which will work.

One issue I have with the array of JSX elements is how to store the these JSX elements in a DB?  I'm guessing I'd have to store them as `Strings` but then how to use them when pull backed form the DB?

Can anyone suggest any working and best practice approaches to these issues?

Comment: You can do `<this.state.headerSize>` when `headerSize` is `'h1'`, do you require it being an incomplete tag/ integer?

Comment: @FabianSchultz: Really?  Does this also work for custom React elements?  Last time I tried ,I got a transpiling error which caused me to use one of the solutions in my answer below...

Comment: Example: http://jsbin.com/kiluwuv/edit?js,output

Comment: @FabianSchultz: Cool mate, good to know.  This doesn't seem to work for _user defined_ React components i.e. for situation (1) where I have defined `<DragNDrop/>`, `<MultipleChoice />` and `<MatchPairs />`, using this.state.assetType[0] doesn't render `<DragNDrop />`

Comment: Yes, the you have to pass in the component (object) itself, not a string.

Comment: Thanks @FabianSchultz, realised this question is in fact a duplicate, so I've voted to close it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Regarding dynamic HTML tags:**

**EDIT:**
  As the docs suggest, ***[Dynamic types can be used at runtime](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#choosing-the-type-at-runtime)*** if first assign to a capitalised variable first:

```
class Quiz extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            questionText: '',
            correctAnswer: [],
            assetType: ['DragNDrop', 'MultipleChoice', 'MatchPairs']
        }
    }
    render() {
        const ElementNameStartsWithCapitalLetter = this.state.assetType[0];
           // ^ -- capital letter here, ensure this works when used in JSX
        return <ElementNameStartsWithCapitalLetter />;
    }
}
```

This is due to the fact that ***[User Defined JSX Components Must BE Capitalized](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized)***.

---

**PREVIOUS SOLUTIONS:**

Using React.createElement:

```js
class Quiz extends React.Component{
  constructor (props){
    super (props);
    this.state = {
      questionText: '',
      correctAnswer: [],
      assetType: ['DragNDrop','MultipleChoice','MatchPairs']
    }
  }
  render(){
    const { questionText, correctAnswer } = this.state;
    {React.createElement(
      [this.props.typeIndex],
      {...questionText, ...correctAnswer}
    );}
  }
}
```

Using conditional rendering:

```
// Conditional rendering works, but yuck!
// One condition per state works
// <b>but can be unnecessarily verbose</>
getHeader() {
  switch(this.state.headerSize){
    case 1:
      return <h1>{ this.state.headerText }; <h1>
    case 2:
      return <h2>{ this.state.headerText }<h2>
    .
    .
    .
    default:
      return null;
  }
}

render (){
  return { this.getHeader() }; // bound correctly in constructor of course :)
}
```